# C# Combobox show current date

Tags: c#, combobox, ext.net

I am trying to create a combobox and assign the displayfield with current date in 2 different formats.
How can I achieve that?
Here is my current code with static values:

```
<ext:ComboBox  runat="server" ID="cmbFormatFFC" DataIndex="DateFormat" FieldLabel="Date Format" Width="400" ForceSelection="true" EmptyText="Select date format...">
       <Items>
              <ext:ListItem Text="1/1/2017" Value="d/M/yyyy" />
              <ext:ListItem Text="1-JAN-2017" Value="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
       </Items>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Please add wpf/winforms tag as combobox appears in both

Comment: Please add your store and model field.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way use object to store current date

```
<script runat="server">
        private object Datedata
        {
            get
            {
                return new object[]
                {                
                    new object[] {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")},
                    new object[] {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")},                
                };
            }
        }
</script>
```

and use it in combobox

```
<ext:ComboBox
            runat="server"                
            DisplayField="date"           
            QueryMode="Local">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server" Data="<%# Datedata %>" AutoDataBind="true">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>                                    
                                <ext:ModelField Name="date" />                                    
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
</ext:ComboBox>
```